# "Elevator Plot" in R - plotting inflow and outflow

Tags: r, plot, graph

I have a question regarding a plot in R.
I have successfully evaluated my data and I now have data from different floors. For every floor and every elevator I want to create a plot.
You can see an example in the attached picture.

Unfortunately, I totally miss the approach. Is this even possible in R? My alternative is to do it by hand in PowerPoint...

[image]

> ```
> input <- c(320, 300, 170, 210, 300, 200, 400)
> out <- c(255, 220, 300, 225, 400, 300, 200)
> level <- c(2, 1, 0, -01, 3, 1, 0)
> elevator <- c(A, A, A, A, B, B, B)
> df <- data.frame(input, out, level, elevator)
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do the job, using `ggplot2`:

```
ggplot(df) +
  # Split per elevator and floor
  facet_grid(level~elevator, as.table=FALSE, labeller=label_both) + 
  # Add arrow "in" and its text
  geom_segment(x=0, y=0, xend=2, yend=0, size=10, color="#A0C080", 
               lineend="butt", linejoin="mitre", 
               arrow=arrow(length=unit(.02, "native"), type="closed")) +
  geom_text(aes(label=input), x=1, y=0, hjust=.5, size=8) +
  # Add arrow "out" and its text
  geom_segment(x=2, y=8, xend=0, yend=8, size=10, color="#C0B0B0", 
               lineend="butt", linejoin="mitre",
               arrow=arrow(length=unit(.02, "native"), type="closed")) +
  geom_text(aes(label=out), x=1, y=8, hjust=.5, size=8) +
  # Draw floors
  geom_rect(xmin=2.5, xmax=4, ymin=-4, ymax=12) +
  # Graphical tweaks
  theme_light() + theme(panel.grid=element_blank()) + ylim(-4,12) + xlim(-.5,3.5)
```

PS: if you really want to include the arrows with 0 count, either include them in your data frame or use `tidyr::complete(...)` (cf the doc)

[image: Result]

Comment: I really appreciate your effort.

That's pretty much what I needed. 

My strength lies more in analyzing and processing data. Your example shows me once again that R is as well very effective for visualizing the results.

Comment: You're welcome! For a next question, it is recommended to explain/show what you have already tried to solve the problem and where you're stuck... although I admit that it is difficult when you have no idea of how to begin